# Is the ytm curve same as the par curve?

Tags: yield-curve

probably a v basic Q, but what is the difference between the ytm curve and the par curve, and given the ytm curve I see in the market how do I build a corresponding par curve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving the par-yield curve](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/9232/deriving-the-par-yield-curve) See both the answer and the comment.

Comment: thanks @noob2 that was helpful